# 100 % CPU usage by HP Probook 4520s

Tags: windows, cpu-usage

I have a HP Probook 4520s with Windows 7 Ultimate, i5 Processor and 2 GB RAM.

For the last couple of days, when I turn on my laptop, the CPU usage rises up to 100% and remains there for 10-15 minutes. No offending process shows up in Task Manager/Process Explorer but the laptop is practically unusable for that time. This has been happening for  2-3 months.

What can I do now?

I don't have any Apple application. I just use the common applications.

Comment: Did you click the "show all processes" button? How about in the resource monitor (can be opened from the performance tab)